# iterate through treeset of integers and store value from next() to an Integer variable

Tags: java, iterator, integer, treeset

I chopped down my program for simplicity, but it is necessary to store the value of next() in a variable because there are other things that I do in the iterator loop that check that value against some stuff. But I'm having trouble storing that value, I get an error saying "incompatible types".

```
import java.util.*;

public class test
{
    public static void main (String [] args)
    {
        String data="34 23 13 5 2 6 9 11";
        Scanner input=new Scanner(data);
        TreeSet set=new TreeSet();
        while (input.hasNextInt())
        {
            Integer num=new Integer(input.nextInt());
            set.add(num);
        }
        Iterator itr=set.iterator();
        while (itr.hasNext())
        {
            Integer num2=itr.next();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

You should use:

`TreeSet<Integer> set = new TreeSet<Integer();`

Once you have that, then when you add, you don't need to instantiate `Integer`, you can just do:

```
set.add(input.nextInt());
```

thanks to autoboxing.

And then when you iterate at the end, you can just do:

```
for (Integer num2 : set) {
}
```

Answer (score 3):

There is a compile error in the line

> Integer num2 = itr.next();

because an Object returned by the Iterator class's next method is equated to a Integer type. Integer belongs to Object type, but Object doesn't belong to Integer type. Therefore, Object type cannot be converted to Integer type since the Object is the super class for all classes in Java.
Here, types are incompatible/ does't match each other. You can convert the Object type to a String and then convert the String to Integer or you can simply cast the Object to Integer.

> Integer num2 = Integer.parseInt(itr.next().toString());
>
> Integer num2 = Integer.valueOf(itr.next().toString());
>
> Integer num2 = (Integer)itr.next();

Answer (score 0):

You have to cast it to an `Integer` type object

```
    Integer num2= (Integer) itr.next();
```

Answer (score 0):

A simple cast should do the trick

```
            Integer num2=(Integer) itr.next();
            System.out.println(num2);
```

Regards, Erwald